# How to prevent duplicate insertion of record with Entity Framework and repository pattern?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I am using a database-first approach and repository pattern. I am calling third party API recursively to get the data and add the result to my table. When I call third party API, there can be new record or existing records, API will return all data all the time.

I want to prevent duplicate insertion of record in my table.

I am using the repository pattern to save the data.

This is my code:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context;        
    protected DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDBContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Add(T entity)
    {
        await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I check if record is already present in table? If already present, then don't add it, else add the record.

Comment: Why not first read from your db by its ID, and if the ID already exists, do nothing?

Comment: it can be heavy operation to check for all records and then insert? is there any efficient solution?

Comment: Also always `return true;` is going to be terrible for debugging and unit testing. add async will be returning a `ValueTask<EntityEntry>` according to the documentation, you need to be checking within that and discerning if the add was successful or not, and then returning the boolean. I don't use Entity Framework myself or else I would provide more code

Comment: ok, thanks for suggestion, i will modify return value.

Comment: "it can be heavy operation to check for all records and then insert" checking for existence by some key value(s) should not be a "heavy operation" even for millions of records. If it is, then you should take a look at your DB design, make sure you have indices where needed or rethink how you're querying for existence.

Comment: How is the primary key defined?

Comment: Primary key is defined to my table's id which does not have relation with Id returned from third party api

Comment: If the id returned from the third part API is guaranteed to be unique, then you need to be checking for that. This is one column so reading that will not be very compute intensive. Checking for the equality of an *entire* record is a different story, hence why your concern isn't all wrong

Comment: Yes, Id returned from third party API would be unique. Thanks. I will check that before insert.